# Add class to pop-up window in android

Tags: java, android, popup, layout-inflater

I have a class `MAIN activity` with its xml VIEW, and also a pop-up xml VIEW.

I was wondering if there was anyway possible to assign to the pop-up VIEW its own CLASS rather than having to create its interactions in the MAIN activity class.

In few words, if class **A** (main activity) has its view **A-VIEW**, how can I make the pop up window **B-VIEW** have its own activity class **B**?

Comment: A popup is a Dialog, not an Activity.

Comment: anyway around this?

Comment: Provide the sample code you have tried if possible.

Comment: Please post some mock ups that show what you want your UI to look like.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make the pop up window 'B-VIEW' have its own activity class B?

Yes, you can make two views with two separate activities. This is very common. You should google something like "start another activity". However, an activity covers the entire screen. It will not display as a popup. To create a popup, you should use Dialog and DialogFragment. Again use google to find more information. You should also learn about fragments because they are commonly used to organize layouts in to reusable chunks.

Comment: I was able to workout a way control the view from a different class.
Thanks to everyone who has tried to help.